# Why Math.random() type is number and Math.random is function?

Tags: javascript

On displaying to console.log command: `typeof Math.random` it returns `function`. But on command `typeof Math.random()` result is `number`.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you add the parenthesis, typeof is evaluating the type of the value returned by the function that is Math.random.

Math.random() returns a number, and typeof will be called using that returned number when the parenthesis are added.

In JavaScript, functions are objects, which is why you're able to use them like other variables.